# Top level stack navigator doesn't see screen options for grandchild stack navigator (react-navigation 5)

Tags: react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-bottom-tab

My app is set up nearly identical to this code snippet in the docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options-resolution/#setting-parent-screen-options-based-on-child-navigators-state:

```
const FeedStack = createStackNavigator();

function FeedStackScreen() {
  return (
    <FeedStack.Navigator>
      <FeedStack.Screen name="Feed" component={FeedScreen} />
      {/* other screens */}
    </FeedStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const ProfileStack = createStackNavigator();

function ProfileStackScreen() {
  return (
    <ProfileStack.Navigator>
      <ProfileStack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
      {/* other screens */}
    </ProfileStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function HomeTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Feed" component={FeedStackScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileStackScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

const RootStack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <RootStack.Navigator>
        <RootStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeTabs} />
        <RootStack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
      </RootStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

The difference is that my versions of `FeedStackScreen` and `ProfileStackScreen` have about 4 or 5 screens in them that each have their own `options` prop that's setting the values of `headerLeft`, `headerRight` and/or `headerTitle`.

The docs say that a parent navigator can only see the settings in its immediate child. So `RootStack` can read screen options for `HomeTabs`, but not for `FeedStackScreen` and `ProfileStackScreen`.

I've tried using this code on my version of `HomeTabs`,

```
React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({ headerTitle: getHeaderTitle(route) });
  }, [navigation, route])
```

but the `route` prop only gives me the name of the `Tab.Screen`...and at minimum I need the name of the `Stack.Screen` that's inside of that tab.

Any suggestions on how to get the `headerLeft`, `headerRight` and `headerTitle` options that are set inside `FeedStackScreen` to be recognizable by `RootStack`?

- Ejected expo app
- react-navigation 5
- xcode 12
- "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.1.tar.gz"

Comment: I've same issue, in react navigation v4 it's working using `ScreenName.defaultOptions`. But after migrating to v5 it's so hard

Comment: Have you found any solution yet? I'm struggling with the same problem atm.